# Microsoft visual studio licence

Tags: visual-c++

I want to work on visual c++ for creation of dll,so do I need to buy its license but I am not sure that can I buy only visual c++ licence or do I need to buy complete visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The newly [released Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is free for many people.  See the licensing terms.